# Add child theme css to <head>

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, parent-child

I have a website (http://lab.eksperimentar.com) and I'm using Delipress theme and it's child.
The problem is: I make the changes inside the child-theme and the page doesn't load the styles.css.

I want to "insert" into the head tag this html element:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" id="delipress-child-style-css" href="http://lab.eksperimentar.com/wp-content/themes/delipress-child/style.css" type="text/css" media="all">
```

If i open the function.php inside the child folder and insert

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" id="delipress-style-css" href="http://lab.eksperimentar.com/wp-content/themes/delipress/style.css?ver=2.5.1" type="text/css" media="all">
</head>
```

it breakes my website, because instead of "inserting" the head tag, it substitutes it.

How to do this without tampering with the father theme?

Answer (score 2):

The correct way would be to use to use the [`wp_register_style()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_style) function, followed by [`wp_enqueue_style()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style).

Both functions need to be hooked into [wp_enqueue_script()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script).

Example From CODEX:

```
// Register style sheet.
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'register_plugin_styles' );

/**
 * Register style sheet.
 */
function register_plugin_styles() {
    wp_register_style( 'my-plugin', plugins_url( 'my-plugin/css/plugin.css' ) );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'my-plugin' );
}
```

You can also skip the register and just use [`wp_enqueue_style()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) alone with the same hook

Read also [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) When using a child theme..

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_my_child_styles', 20 );
function load_my_child_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-theme', get_stylesheet_uri() );
}
```

Another ( less recommended ) option, if you have only simple CSS and you would like to output it directly into the `HEAD` would be using the [`wp_head()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head) action

```
<?php 
    function add_styles()
    {
        ?>
        <style type="text/css">
        .menu ul li.world a {
            background: url(<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/<?php echo get_option(THEME_PREFIX . 'intro_image'); ?>) repeat scroll 0%;
        }

        .m ul li.me a {
            background: url(<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/<?php echo get_option(THEME_PREFIX . 'slider_image'); ?>) repeat scroll 0%;
        }

    </style>
    <?php 
    wp_head
    }

    add_action('wp_head', 'add_styles'); ?>
```

Please note the opening and closing `PHP` tags

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to edit the `functions.php` file; you should open the `header.php` file located inside your child-theme folder and then add the following code inside the `<head></head>` tags:

`<link rel="stylesheet" id="delipress-child-style-css" href="http://lab.eksperimentar.com/wp-content/themes/delipress-child/style.css" type="text/css" media="all">`

Comment: There is not a `header.php` file inside my child theme's folder, only a `style.css` and `functions.php`. I'll create one and let you know

Comment: you should create a copy of the header.php file which is inside your parent theme and then move that copied header.php file inside your child-theme folder. Once that's done, follow the steps which I've mentioned in my main answer.

Comment: @FahadHasan - the correct way wouldbe to use `wp_enqueue_style().`